# Entity Framework Error on multiple Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a work object:

```
public class Work{
public int WorkId { get; set; }
public virtual Work RelatedWork { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Work> RelatedMultipleWorks { get; set; }
}
```

I'm generating an Work object like this :

```
Work myWork = new Work();

work mywork2 = new Work();
work mywork3 = new Work();

myWork.RelatedMultipleWorks.add(mywork2);
myWork.RelatedMultipleWorks.add(mywork3);
```

On `DbSaveChanges`, I get this exception :

> Entities in 'Database.Works' participate in the 'Company_CompanyWorks'
>   relationship. 0 related 'Company_CompanyWorks_Source' were found. 1
>   'Company_CompanyWorks_Source' is expected.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are modelling a one-to-many relationship, your related work requires to have foreign key of what relates to it. Add a `Work` property to your `Work` class.

Edit: Example

```
public class Work{
// Primary key
public int WorkId { get; set; }

// Foreign key
public virtual Work Work { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Work> RelatedMultipleWorks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I didn't understand what _"Add a Work property to your Work class."_ means, can you describe it? Maybe with an example? Thanks.

Comment: Added exaample.

Comment: There is a field `public virtual Work RelatedWork { get; set; }` in my original code, Could you tell me how I can use it? Thanks.

Comment: Could you update your question with that? Right now it only shows the `ICollection`

Comment: Should I use RelatedWork for adding new related records?

Comment: With that your `Work`-`Work` relationship should work fine. The error message mentions some error with `CompanyWork` relationship. Can you post full code of `Work` and `CompanyWork`?